# Converting types from CGSize to SizeF

Tags: c#, xamarin

Trying to do dinamicly changing label size which depends of the text size. Getting error : 
[image]

```
            UILabel addressLabel = new UILabel();
            float labelWidth = (float)addressLabel.Frame.Width;
            SizeF size = ((NSString)addressLabel.Text).StringSize(addressLabel.Font, constrainedToSize: new SizeF(labelWidth, 100),
                    lineBreakMode: UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
            var labelFrame = addressLabel.Frame;
            labelFrame.Size = new SizeF(labelWidth, size.Height);
            addressLabel.Frame = labelFrame;
```

How could i convert this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, you can use explicit cast to convert `CGSize` to `SizeF`. You can check that this conversion exists in the [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/CoreGraphics.CGSize/).

```
SizeF size = ( SizeF )((NSString)addressLabel.Text).StringSize(
                 addressLabel.Font,
                 constrainedToSize: new SizeF(labelWidth, 100),
                 lineBreakMode: UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
```

You can also convert it manually. You can see that `CGSize` has `Height` and `Width` properties, same as the `SizeF`. What you can do then is:

```
CGSize sizeOfString = ((NSString)addressLabel.Text).StringSize(
        addressLabel.Font,
        constrainedToSize: new SizeF(labelWidth, 100),
        lineBreakMode: UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
SizeF size = new SizeF( ( float )sizeOfString.Width, ( float )sizeOfString.Height );
```

Note that `CGSize` is a iOS type and uses `nfloat` instead of `float`, so you need to perform the conversion to `float` manually.